# ES6 object initializer dynamic property value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible in React function component using ES6 to initialize property value using a function?
Eg below:

```
const getMyPropertyValue = (condition) => {
   switch(condition){
       case "a": return "string a";
       case "b": return "string b";
    }
}

const myObject = {
     property1: 'value1',
     property2: 'value2',
     property3: getMyPropertyValue('b')
}
```

The property name is known, the property value is dynamic.  I would like to have an inline function to set property3's value. Is that possible?

Comment: React.js is just javascript with JSX, If it is possible in JS then definitely you can do it in React.js

Comment: Do you want something like `prop3: val === 'a' ? 'string a' : 'string b',` ? [More here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Yes, you can use the code above as is.

Comment: Used LaytonGB's solution.  Thankyou very much